# Slider con JS solo funciona en chrome

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un slider automático y en chrome me funciona pero en mozilla y opera no sale ninguna imagen. Con esto descarto que esté llamando mal al documento pero no consigo ver el error, ¿me podeis ayudar?

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function (){
        
    var imagenes = [];
    imagenes[0] = '../Imagenes/slider1.jpg';
    imagenes[1] = '../Imagenes/slider2.jpg';
    imagenes[2] = '../Imagenes/slider3.jpg';
    var long_imagenes = imagenes.length;

    var cnt = 0;
    function cambiarImagenes(){


        document.img_slider.src = imagenes[cnt];

        if(cnt < (long_imagenes-1)){
            cnt = cnt +1;
        }else{
            cnt = 0;
        }
    }

    setInterval(cambiarImagenes,3000);
});
```

```html
<div id="slider_cont">
    <img name="img_slider" id="img_slider">
</div>
```

**EDITO**
Gracias a los comentarios hasta ahora creo que el error está en la ruta, pues si pongo los enlaces que hay el snippet si que funciona.

Mi raiz:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo lo que hago es salir de la carpeta js, entrar en imagenes y definir la imagen que quiero tarbajar.

Comment: El código está incompleto: ¿Qué es `document.img_slider`?

Comment: @PabloLozano ya lo he añadido, pensé que no haría falta. Es la llamada a la imagen que tengo en mi html

Comment: Prueba poner una condición que las imágenes estén cargadas.

Comment: El código funciona en Firefox, una vez que pongo imágenes reales (te he montado la demo en la pregunta), lo que me sorprende un poco porque no sé si `document[<id>]` es un estándar válido para abreviar `document.getElementById`

Comment: He estado investigando y deberías usar `document.getElementById`, ya  `document.<id>` no es un estándar (es un invento de Microsoft para IE): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Comment: Yo he probado en Chrome, Firefox, IE11 y Opera sobre win7 y en todos funciona correctamente.

Comment: @PabloLozano estaba haciendo con el `name` en vez del `id` pero ya lo he corregido. Gracias a vuestros comentarios, veo que mi error está en la ruta definida en el array. Pero no veo el fallo, he editado y añadido una imagen para ver la raiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré el error, se trata de la ruta mal puesta. Pues aunque esté dentro de un fichero de `js` realmente estoy modificando el `html`.

Yo tenía:

```
imagenes[0] = '../Imagenes/slider1.jpg';
imagenes[1] = '../Imagenes/slider2.jpg';
imagenes[2] = '../Imagenes/slider3.jpg';
```

Y es:

```
imagenes[0] = 'Imagenes/slider1.jpg';
imagenes[1] = 'Imagenes/slider2.jpg';
imagenes[2] = 'Imagenes/slider3.jpg';
```

Muchas gracias a las ayudas previas, gracias a ellas he podido encontrar el error.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque a mi me funciona perfectamente en Firefox (versión para Ubuntu), te aconsejo que pruebes a sustituir

```
document.img_slider.src = imagenes[cnt];
```

por

```
let slider = document.getElementById('img_slider');
slider.src = imagenes[cnt];
```

Que es el estándar para búsqueda de elementos en el documento actual.